# Why is warning disable 429 not working to surpress unreachable code?

Tags: c#, compiler-warnings, pragma

I am trying to suppress a warning in a very simple C# file, but it is not working and I cannot find what I am doing wrong here. Why is Visual Studio still showing "Unreachable code detected" in this small piece of code.

```
#pragma warning disable 429

// I've got the number from:
// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ch1a3w5.aspx

// This below does work, so I might have the wrong number for the warning?
// #pragma warning disable 

using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("test");
            if (false)
                return;
            return;
            MessageBox.Show("test");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It was just a test, an example, how I should work with #pragma disable, Thorsten. Hence I just tried a simple warning message, and tried to suppress that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're disabling 429, but you want to disable 0162 - that's the warning number you're getting:

```
#pragma warning disable 0162
```

Always look for the specific warning number in the build output.

(And of course, it's generally not a good idea to disable warnings anyway... try to fix the code rather than disabling the warning.)

Comment: Thank you. It works. In the MSDN page it says: Unreachable *expression* code detected. Hence I was looking at the wrong warning that seemed really simular? Thanks again, this was frustrating me for half an hour, and I was thinking: am I blind or what?

Comment: @JaJa: Yes, it's a different warning. From the page: "This error occurs whenever part of an expression in your code is unreachable." In your case it isn't *part of an expression* - it's a whole statement. But in general, you should look at what the compiler's telling you rather than anything else :)

Comment: Thanks Jon. Is there a complete list of warnings somewhere? 162 is not in the list on MSDN. Anyway, I am not really trying to suppress *that* specific error. What I am actually trying to do is make a console program that generates my own warnings, give that as post build step to the compilation of another program. I have done that. But now I wonder if I can assign a user defined warning number to my own warning, and then use #pragma to suppress my own warning in certain files in the project. And then the first step was, trying to suppress a standard warning.

Comment: @JaJa: There may be a complete list somewhere, but I've never seen it. I always just look at the warning I'm getting instead.

Comment: For what its worth, I find this useful when I WANT to have unreachable code.  For instance, I have an authentication validation method.  Now, there shouldn't be any way to get all the way to the end, but if a coder down the line were to create a bug so that there is a path to get to the end, I want to make damned sure that it always returns an unauthenticated result.